# 500.22 Intelligencia.UrlRewriter Integrated Pipeline Error

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms, iis-express

I created a new web application in VS2015 using the .NET 4.6.2 WebForms template.  I added the Intelligencia.UrlRewriter NuGet package (found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Intelligencia.UrlRewriter/)).  I then went to my web.config and added a RegEx if statement to the rewriter section:

```
<if url="^(.+)/tenant/(.[^/]+)(.+)$">
    <set property="TenantName" value="$2" />
    <rewrite to="$1$3"/>
</if>
```

The logic should parse the URL and set the first part to the $1 value (i.e. http://localhost/) and then set $2 value to the tenant name that is supplied (i.e. MyTenant) and then set the context value of TenantName to the $2 value.  Lastly, it should set the $3 value as the last part of the URL (i.e. TenantLoader.aspx).  I can't verify that this portion is working, I just know that the last action in the if statement is failing.  The rewrite method should be concatenating the $1 and the $3 values together (i.e. http://localhost/TenantLoader.aspx) but it is not.  Instead, I get a 500.22 error from IIS Express with the following error message:

> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated
>   managed pipeline mode.

With the **Most likely causes**:

> This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpModules
>   section.

Anyone?

Comment: Now, instead of using an outdated 3rd party package, I would be interested in using ASP.NET Routing if I could get it to work.  It routes just fine, but I cannot retrieve the route values that I configured in the page route.  Suggestions?

Comment: It would appear that there is a problem if you have the route as the same name as a physical page (that's just stupid).  So in my URL, I would like to have something like http://www.multitenantsite.com/tenant/sometenantid/tenant.aspx and it pick up sometenantid, but it doens't.  It just routes me to Tenant.aspx with no RouteData.